# Rails + Mongoid + Strong Parms failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters, mongoid4

So, I'm relatively new to ruby and rails.  I'm playing around with mongoid for my database, though the only knowledge I hold is using active record.

I created a fresh project, being sure to skip active record so that I didn't have to perform the steps to remove it later in favor of mongoid.

I created a scaffold `rails g scaffold user` and went on my way looking around.  So since I know that mongo is a schemaless db, I went to the model and modified it like so:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name,         :type => String

end
```

pretty simple, just one field ( for now ).  So, I added the field to my form via the normal route `<%= text_field_tag :name %>`  and restarted my server `rails s`

I went to the dev site, and everything appears to work as it should.  So, I submit the form and it submits.  Looking at the DB, a document is created only without the name field.  Remembering about `strong attributes` for active record, I went to the `users_controller.rb` and modified it like so:

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name)
end
```

At this point, not remembering if I need to restart the server or not -- I do, just to be on the safe side.  Once the server is running I go to the site, and submit the form and it tells me:

`param is missing or the value is empty: user`

Not sure what I've done wrong here, or if with mongoid I even need the .require line ( in all honesty I don't know what it does, except I thought it was requiring that these fields in permit are being submitted to the user model ) as removing the .require portion and just doing `params.permit(:name)` processes the information as it should.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
$ rails --version
Rails 4.2.1
```

and my GemFile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'mongoid', '~> 4.0.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
#gem 'rspec-its'
# Use Unicorn as the app server
#gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
#gem 'font-awesome-rails', '~> 4.3.0.0'
#gem 'foundation-rails'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.5.0'
end
group :development do
  gem 'quiet_assets', '~> 1.1.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.4.4'
  gem 'capybara-email', '~> 2.4.0'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 2.8.0'
end
```

Any ideas of what I've done wrong?  Only code associated with this is what was generated by `rails new` and `rails g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you don't need to restart the rails server for any of the changes you've described.

The error you're getting just means that `params[:user]` is empty (or missing). If you check your development.log you'll see that `params[:name]` is set instead.

This is because you've used `text_field_tag`, which doesn't name the input so as to nest the value in params[:user].

Assuming you're using `form_for` to create your form, you want to instead do

```
f.text_field :name
```

Comment: You are right, it is using `form_for` and modifying the markup to reflect that change as you have described solves the issue immediately.  Still getting the hang of this ruby thing ( coming from a PHP background of 15+ years )

Also, thanks for the info on restarting the server.  I know that I need to whenever I modify the gemfile, but outside of that I couldn't remember so figure I would just to be safe.